# POLYGON Node Not Syncing Fast Even After DOWNLOADING FROM SNAPSHOT

Tags: polygon

I Have tried to make deploy a node of Polygon Mainnet and I am trying to  make it full sync.
Its Not syncing for 5 Days. I have downloaded Snapshot and Extracted it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.